# CSS Selector *= ambiguous id + distinction

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem with the CSS-Selector *= and an ambiguous id. The problem is, that I need to find a certain string in a long id. For Example:

Find tree in id=house-tree-log. I do this like this:

```
var string = "tree";
var elem = $("div[id*="+string+"]");
```

The problem is, that I also have a case like this (s at the end):

```
var string = "trees";
var elem = $("div[id*="+string+"]");
```

Is there any way I can distinct them? It does not have to be pure CSS, even if I would prefer it.

Comment: Can you not search for `tree-` and `trees-`? Or better yet, use a `class` or `data` attribute to identify the elements individually.

Comment: Doesn't `[id|=tree]` return only elements with the string `'tree'` followed by a hyphen? Which presumably prevents a match on `trees-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "word boundary" control character in either the JS or CSS specs, so you have a couple of options, neither of which are perfect.

First off, you can create your own standard word boundary (your example uses `-`, if that's consistent across all your IDs, then that would work) to do something like this:

```
var elem = $( 'div[id='+string+', div[id^="'+string+'-"], div[id*="-'+string+'-"], div[id$="-'+string+'"] ')
```

This matches the exact string, any starting with `string-`, containing `-string-` or ending with `-string`.

This has the benefit of only selecting the elements you want, although it will run 4 selections, which means if you have a lot of `div`s, you could really load up the processor.

---

The alternative would be selecting all `div`s (optionally in a scope) then iterating them and doing a regex match on their ID, where you CAN use word boundaries:

```
var elem = $('div').filter(function() { return this.id.match( new RegExp('\\b'+string+'\\b') ); });
```

Comment: Thank you. The $ was what I was looking for. Sorry the example was badly chosen. There is no hyphen at the end.

Comment: @stiller_leser Updated with the regex example. Also, could you upvote any helpful answer, and mark the most helpful as accepted? :-)

Comment: I wanted to... Apparently there is a time limit on accepting answers. Anyway. Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can check if it has a hyphen after it too:

```
var elem = $("div[id*="+string+"-]");
```